# Entropy column doesn't exist

Tags: python, pyspark, k-means

I'm trying to follow along with the code examples from Chapter 5 of Advanced Analytics with PySpark.  For context, the chapter is about k_means clustering and the section that I am on is focusing on is talking about finding an optimal value for k using a method for calculating weighted average entropy.  However, while following along with the textbook, I get an error that I am unsure how to fix.

Here is the code from the textbook:
part 1:

```
from math import log

def entropy(counts):
values = [c for c in counts if (c > 0)]
n = sum(values)
p = [v/n for v in values]
return sum([-1*(p_v) * log(p_v) for p_v in p])
```

part 2:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as fun
from pyspark.sql import Window

cluster_label = pipeline_model.\
                    transform(data).\
                    select("cluster", "label")

 df = cluster_label.\
    groupBy("cluster", "label").\
    count().orderBy("cluster")

 w = Window.partitionBy("cluster")

 p_col = df['count'] / fun.sum(df['count']).over(w)
 with_p_col = df.withColumn("p_col", p_col)

 result = with_p_col.groupBy("cluster").\
            agg(-fun.sum(col("p_col") * fun.log2(col("p_col")))\
                    .alias("entropy"),
            fun.sum(col("count"))\
                    .alias("cluster_size"))

 result = result.withColumn('weightedClusterEntropy',col('entropy') * 
 col('cluster_size'))

 weighted_cluster_entropy_avg = result.\
                    agg(fun.sum(col('weightedClusterEntropy'))).\
                    collect()
 weighted_cluster_entropy_avg[0][0]/data.count()
```

Meanwhile here is the stack trace of the error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 23, in <module>
  File "/opt/conda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 3036, in withColumn
    return DataFrame(self._jdf.withColumn(colName, col._jc), self.sparkSession)
  File "/opt/conda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
  File "/opt/conda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 196, in deco
    raise converted from None
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Column 'entropy' does not exist. Did you mean one of the following? [cluster, cluster_size, (- sum((p_col * LOG2(p_col))) AS entropy)];
'Project [cluster#96820, (- sum((p_col * LOG2(p_col))) AS entropy)#96892, cluster_size#96891L, ('entropy * cluster_size#96891L) AS weightedClusterEntropy#96896]
+- Aggregate [cluster#96820], [cluster#96820, -sum((p_col#96878 * LOG2(p_col#96878))) AS (- sum((p_col * LOG2(p_col))) AS entropy)#96892, sum(count#96873L) AS cluster_size#96891L]
   +- Project [cluster#96820, label#142, count#96873L, p_col#96878]
      +- Project [cluster#96820, label#142, count#96873L, _we0#96879L, (cast(count#96873L as double) / cast(_we0#96879L as double)) AS p_col#96878]
         +- Window [sum(count#96873L) windowspecdefinition(cluster#96820, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$())) AS _we0#96879L], [cluster#96820]
            +- Project [cluster#96820, label#142, count#96873L]
               +- Sort [cluster#96820 ASC NULLS FIRST], true
                  +- Aggregate [cluster#96820, label#142], [cluster#96820, label#142, count(1) AS count#96873L]
                     +- Project [cluster#96820, label#142]
                        +- Project [duration#101, protocol_type#102, service#103, flag#104, src_bytes#105, dst_bytes#106, land#107, wrong_fragment#108, urgent#109, hot#110, num_failed_logins#111, logged_in#112, num_compromised#113, root_shell#114, su_attempted#115, num_root#116, num_file_creations#117, num_shells#118, num_access_files#119, num_outbound_cmds#120, is_host_login#121, is_guest_login#122, count#123, srv_count#124, ... 20 more fields]
                           +- Project [duration#101, protocol_type#102, service#103, flag#104, src_bytes#105, dst_bytes#106, land#107, wrong_fragment#108, urgent#109, hot#110, num_failed_logins#111, logged_in#112, num_compromised#113, root_shell#114, su_attempted#115, num_root#116, num_file_creations#117, num_shells#118, num_access_files#119, num_outbound_cmds#120, is_host_login#121, is_guest_login#122, count#123, srv_count#124, ... 19 more fields]
                              +- Project [_c0#17 AS duration#101, _c1#18 AS protocol_type#102, _c2#19 AS service#103, _c3#20 AS flag#104, _c4#21 AS src_bytes#105, _c5#22 AS dst_bytes#106, _c6#23 AS land#107, _c7#24 AS wrong_fragment#108, _c8#25 AS urgent#109, _c9#26 AS hot#110, _c10#27 AS num_failed_logins#111, _c11#28 AS logged_in#112, _c12#29 AS num_compromised#113, _c13#30 AS root_shell#114, _c14#31 AS su_attempted#115, _c15#32 AS num_root#116, _c16#33 AS num_file_creations#117, _c17#34 AS num_shells#118, _c18#35 AS num_access_files#119, _c19#36 AS num_outbound_cmds#120, _c20#37 AS is_host_login#121, _c21#38 AS is_guest_login#122, _c22#39 AS count#123, _c23#40 AS srv_count#124, ... 18 more fields]
                                 +- Relation [_c0#17,_c1#18,_c2#19,_c3#20,_c4#21,_c5#22,_c6#23,_c7#24,_c8#25,_c9#26,_c10#27,_c11#28,_c12#29,_c13#30,_c14#31,_c15#32,_c16#33,_c17#34,_c18#35,_c19#36,_c20#37,_c21#38,_c22#39,_c23#40,... 18 more fields] csv
```

Can someone tell me why this error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the minus in front of the sum is not part of the parentheses. As you can see your DF contains the following column:

```
(- sum((p_col * LOG2(p_col))) AS entropy)
```

which indicates that only the `sum((p_col * LOG2(p_col)))` expression got aliased.

Could you try:

```
 result = with_p_col.groupBy("cluster").\
            agg((-fun.sum(col("p_col") * fun.log2(col("p_col"))))
                    .alias("entropy"),
            fun.sum(col("count"))
                    .alias("cluster_size"))
```